# Ruby on Rails: Basic Iteration of an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

I want to iterate an array into my code but don't know how. I think this should be simple. I have an array of numbers and I want to substitute the numbers I am pointing to with the red arrow.

This is driving me nuts. Thanks.

Comment: is it true that the field names are like `card_type1`, `card_type2`.

Comment: Yes. Do you have any advice on how to do this? I am so new at this.

Comment: yes I have, i will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that the field names are like `card_type1`, `card_type2` in the database table.

try this,

```
<% @numbers.each do |n| %>
<%= f.input :"card_type#{n}", .......
```

If any confusion please feel free to comment here

Comment: YES! This was what I was looking for. I just didn't know the proper syntax. Thanks